# Floating Point Modulo Assembly on ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

On x86, there is a floating-point modulo instruction called **fprem**, which divide stack element 0 by stack element 1 and leave the remainder in stack element 0.

Now I'm developing fmodl functions on the ARM platform. I wonder if there are alternative instructions on the **ARM** platform ?

Comment: Have you looked at existing open-source `fmod` implementations?  x87 is fairly unique in having many non-basic operations supported in hardware (actually just microcode; [`fprem`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fprem) is *very* slow on modern x86 compared to basic ops like +-*, and / and sqrt.)  Also, `fprem` is only a partial remainder:  *It can, however, reduce the exponent of ST(0) by no more than 63 in one execution of the instruction* .  Also, as the manual says, use [`fprem1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fprem1) for IEEE remainder, but still only partial remainder.

Comment: @Barmar: Floating point modulo is a different and harder problem than for integer.  It's also true (AFAIK) that there's no FP remainder instruction on ARM, but the duplicate you chose doesn't say anything about that one way or the other.  For example, ARM doesn't have an instruction for integer square roots, but does for floating point.  (Most ISAs do since it's an IEEE basic operation, required to be correctly-rounded, which HW helps for.)

Comment: Oops, didn't notice "floating point"

Comment: See https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=68&sid=49496d64ce03fa16e0a0b19567e76c48 / https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/9d324e13457cf67b44be04f49a4a0036bb188a89/vectormath_trig.h#L105 for range-reduction (mod Pi) in trig functions, done with an attempt at higher precision than naive, using FMA operations if available.

Answer (score 1):

Long time since I touched ARM but as far as I remember there isn't `fprem`. You could however use `vcvt`.

Reading this NEON [docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102474/0100/Fundamentals-of-Armv8-Neon-technology), I see that it might be possible with utilizing NEON instructions. In [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/Vector-Floating-point-Programming/Floating-point-registers) section, you would find documentation about FP-registers.

[This](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Intrinsics-Reference/Floating-point/VCVT) documentation would help you with `vcvt`

Here is how the implementation would go using `vcvt`.

```
vdiv s2, s0, s1  @@ Compute s0/s1
vcvt.s32.f32 s2, s2 @@ Floor the fraction
vcvt.f32.s32 s2, s2 @@ Convert back to float
vmul  s2, s2, s1  @@ Multiply by divisor
vsub  s0, s0, s2  @@ Compute the remainder
```

Thanks [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) for pointing out that the original answer wasn't sufficient for larger inputs. Hence I tried to implement a well rounded answer for ARM with double precision inputs. In this answer, we also cover few edge cases such as signs and NAN.

I tried to get two designs, where first for double precision floats and second; single precision floats.

This following code will cover for double precision inputs (Double). For 32 bit systems, you could swap the `d` registers with `s`. The implementation would, more or less, be like this. I tested it with larger inputs and got sufficient result.

For `nan_constant`, you would use `0x7fc00000`

```
.global fmod
fmod:
    vcmp.f64 d1, #0
    vmrs APSR_nzcv,FPSCR
    beq NaN
    vabs.f64 d2, d1
    vabs.f64 d3, d0

find_largest_n:
    vcmp.f64 d3, d2
    vmrs APSR_nzcv,FPSCR
    blt finish
    vsub.f64 d3, d3, d2
    b find_largest_n

finish:
    vcmp.f64 d0, #0   @check the sign of the original dividend
    vmrs APSR_nzcv,FPSCR
    bge check_divisor
    vneg.f64 d3, d3  @ Negate d3 if the dividend is negativ

check_divisor:
    vcmp.f64 d1, #0   @check the sign o f the original divisor
    vmrs APSR_nzcv,FPSCR
    bge persist
    vneg.f64 d3, d3  @ negate again if the original divisor ws negative

persist:
    vmov r0, r1, d3
    bx lr

NaN: @for non-numbers
    @ Assuming the NaN constant is at label nan_constant
    ldr r0, =nan_constant
    ldrd r0, r1, [r0]
    bx lr

.section .data
nan_constant:
    .quad 0x7ff8000000000000 @constant NaN for double precision
```

Comment: This is simple algorithm works ok for easy cases, but achieving more precision is possible.  Subtracting two nearby floats loses a lot of precision, so the results will be very bad for a big dividend and a small non-round divisor.  Also, some `float` values will overflow an `int32_t`, so that's not a safe way to round to the nearest integer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing it out. I tried a way to also cover the edge cases with larger inputs. For 32 bit, it would use the same logic with corresponding register keys

Comment: To return a NaN, normally do something like divide `0` which will also raise the appropriate FP exceptions.  Then you have a NaN in FP regs, and can `vmov` it to integer.  Is the second version using repeated-subtraction?  That could take hours or maybe years (up to 2^53 x the time per iteration), or in the worst case an infinite loop if the divisor is less than 1ulp of the dividend.  It don't think it will accumulate any less error in the cases where it does work.  Maybe more, since there are many rounding steps along the way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm actually working on a long double-precision version. Does the NEON instruction support operations on this type of data (long double, f128)?

Comment: @SnowDance1997: ARM (including NEON and all other extensions that I know of) has no hardware support at all for f128, so you are going to have to write a purely software implementation.